# How to scroll to specific element

Tags: javascript

I try to create an effect that when a user is on the hero section(which uses 100vh) and scrolls down it immediately scrolls to a specific element and same when the user is at that specific element and scrolls up it takes him to the hero section

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var x = $("#scroll-to").offset();
        var height1 = $("#scroll-to").outerHeight();
        var y = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        var z = (x.top + height1) - y;
        if(z < $(window).height()){
             
      document.querySelector('#scroll-anchor').scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth'
    });
             
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's a feature which was described billion times before, try to search a little bit.

Comment: OK, and what's going wrong? What's your question? Where's your code?

Comment: I tried many codes I found here but none seem to fit my needs

Answer (score 1):

using HTML id and  tag and using the id as href in the link

```css
.blue{
  background-color: blue;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height:700px;
}

.red{
  background-color: red;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height:700px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#red">red</a>

<div class="blue" id="blue"></div>
<div class="red" id="red"></div>
```

Comment: I tried using this code but for some reason when its scrolls to the element you can go up 

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var x = $("#scroll-to").offset();
        var height1 = $("#scroll-to").outerHeight();
        var y = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        var z = (x.top + height1) - y;
        if(z < $(window).height()){
             
             $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#scroll-anchor").offset().top }, 1500);
             
        }
    });
});